# ether type for adding custom protocol on ethernet frame

Tags: sockets, ethernet, raw-sockets

I want to use send and receive data using raw socket communication with my own custom protocol. i won't be using TCP/IP/UDP stack. I want to send directly data using destination MAC address with payload of Ethernet frame with data i defined.

i see from the list
https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml
that the 65535  FFFF    -   -   Reserved    [RFC1701] , is this range i can use ?

My question is for this, what should be the Ethernet Type I should be using, is there any Ethernet type for general usage that any one can use or we have to register it through IEEE Registration Authority ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use any Ethertype that doesn't collide with any protocol in use in your network.

You *should* use only Ethertypes that you have previously registered with <del>IANA</del> IEEE, especially for anything you're planning to sell at some time.

Comment: i see https://standards.ieee.org/products-services/regauth/ethertype/index.html where we can apply, so we have to apply iana and iEEE both ?

Comment: Sorry, make that IEEE. IANA is just showing the IEEE list.

Comment: so there is no particular ethertype which is reserved for local use, as in our use case, it will be used inside our local lan only for a specific setup where we are in full control